# image size as per the div size in the app

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a mobile app on phonegap.

I have a scenario where people will be attaching images and uploading images.

So whatever the div size is I want my image to take that much size regardless of it's original size.

Below is chunk of the code

```
  <div class="comment-div">
    <h2>User 2 <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
      <p>When we will be able to build a society of humans on Mars? </p>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-div odd">
    <h2>User 1 <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
      <p>I think if you managed to keep your hand still in the bucket, you would suffer from significant muscle atrophy. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-div">
    <img src="http://webcareinfoway.com/images/Web_pics/android-logo-transparent.png" alt="Smiley face">
   </div> 

   <div class="comment-div">
     <img src="http://vectorlogo4u.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Google-New-2015-logo-720x340.png" alt="Smiley face">
   </div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3aau3ks7/1/) for the same. Please help

Comment: add your css code

Comment: Set ```width:100%``` styling to your ```img``` tag.

Comment: @suraj I'm added an answer below ,check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think img with width and height 100% will work.

```
img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3aau3ks7/2/

Comment: both height and width of fixed size?

Comment: @Suraj, it is not fixed size, it will get adjusted according to outer div width and height.....in other words img width and height will be same as that of outer div.

Comment: and if you want each image comment of same height, just set .comment-div height as fixed one like <br>
    .comment-div { height: 300px; }

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet. 
Also, If I wish to add the video as well, How do I make it responsive?

For e.g.

`<div class="comment-div">
                            <video>
                                <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                            </video>`

Comment: but depending on image resolution, only one of width or height will be fully contained inside outer div

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me..

`<div class="comment-div"><video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item img "><source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                            </video>
                        </div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131689/discussion-between-jaspreet-singh-and-suraj).

Answer (score 2):

add width `100%`

```
.comment-div img{
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.comment-div img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This will disturb the aspect ratio of image and it will look distorted.

Comment: use svg image.. image quality will not disturb

Comment: I'm not about quality. I'm about aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

add the style

```
.comment-div img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
.comment-div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

to your style sheet it works fine,I'm added the snippet below.

```css
comment-div h2 {
    width: 100% !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    color: #673a9a !important;
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
}

.question-div p {
    display: block;
}
.comment-div p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #000;
}

.comment-div.odd:after {
    bottom: 15px;
    left: auto;
    right: -7px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #bbd7ed transparent;
}

.comment-only .comment-div {
    background-color: #95d6ff;
}
.comment-div {
    background-color: #6ee3ed;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.comment-div img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
.comment-div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

```html
<div class="comment-div">
    <h2>User 2 <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
      <p>When we will be able to build a society of humans on Mars? </p>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-div odd">
    <h2>User 1 <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
      <p>I think if you managed to keep your hand still in the bucket, you would suffer from significant muscle atrophy. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-div">
    <img src="http://webcareinfoway.com/images/Web_pics/android-logo-transparent.png" alt="Smiley face">
   </div> 

   <div class="comment-div">
     <img src="http://vectorlogo4u.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Google-New-2015-logo-720x340.png" alt="Smiley face">
   </div>
```